# Self-destroying Python script

Tags: python, self-destruction

For no particular reason (mainly just the joy of experimentation), I'm looking for a way to write a python script, that self-destroys after execution. One simple approach would be to determine the file, that is being called from the file itself and delete it afterwards as in:

```
import os
DIR_PATH = os.path.realpath(__file__)
os.remove(DIR_PATH)
```

which fails for obvious reasons (at least on windows) as the file is hold by the python process. How would I go about to achieve this? Bonus karma points for a real-world application on why anyone would do this.

Comment: Well, your script works on debian :)

Comment: Run the delete in a subprocess.

Comment: Because Debian can!

Comment: Of course, `os.remove` only removes *one* link to the script, not *all* links.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the windows behaviour, because i'm on linux, but obvious solution is to spawn another one process, which will remove file, maybe with a little delay. I think you can just send a command into shell

Comment: Regarding Subprocesses: Is this defined behaviour to kill the parent while a child process is active?

Comment: If you want to have fun then write the python file (this works if you need one file only), put it on git as public and then run it like this:

`curl https://gitlab.com/username/project/raw/master/demo.py | python -`

this way, the script will just be executed, not save and no need to delete.

you usually don't do this, but this is how I proceed with my installers